# Java Socket - Inverse Communication

Tags: java, sockets

I have many clients that are waiting for server messages. So the client make accept() and wait for server. When server have messages, open a connection to the client and send messages, after that, close the communication and the cycle restart.

I've seen usually the inverse approach, where the server do accept() and client connect to it. I've wrote this code but the client (that do accept() ) is blocked on point **3** and the server (that create the connection to the client) is blocked on point **2**.

Sure i have some problems in my code (dont know where), but... this is the correct way ?

**The client (that do accept() and wait for new messages)**

```
try {
                System.out.println("Waiting..");
                receiver = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("1");
                ObjectInput fromServerReader = new ObjectInputStream(receiver.getInputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream toServerWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(receiver.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("2");
                toServerWriter.writeObject("dummy");
                toServerWriter.flush();
                System.out.println("3");

                ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent = (ScheduledEvent) fromServerReader.readObject();

                System.out.println("4");

                receiver.close();
                System.out.println("5");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // Should never happen
            }
```

**The server (that when have new message to send to client, create the
 connection)**

```
try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(sendToUser
                    .getMachineName());
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            log.debug("1");
            ObjectOutputStream toClientWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream fromClientReader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            log.debug("2");

            String read = (String)fromClientReader.readObject();
            log.debug("3");

            // Compose the message
            ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent = new ScheduledEvent();
            scheduledEvent.setSubject(event.getSubject());
            scheduledEvent.setMessage(event.getText());

            log.debug("4");
            toClientWriter.writeObject(scheduledEvent);
            toClientWriter.flush();
            log.debug("5");

            socket.close();
            log.debug("6");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO handle
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO handle
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In client code, instead of using

```
PrintWriter writer;
```

Use

```
ObjectOutputStream writer;
```

And then use

```
writer.writeObject("dummy");
writer.flush();
```

Comment: Look my update, i've just placed a "Waiting.." and changed the stream to Object. The strange thing is that server (that should send the real object) write 1-2-3-4-5-6 (finish all the cycle). The client write: Waiting - 1 - 2 - 3 waiting... The output 4 is totally jumped (where i read ScheduledEvent) and back to Waiting...

Comment: Wait i have understand... I got a damn ClassNotFoundException that was not trapped!

Comment: What is stack trace for that exception?

Comment: I've created the ScheduledEvent class in my server project and just copied that class in Client Project, (they are in different name packages). For some reason, the Client is trying to find that class in a wrong package. Sure, all compile well otherwise I would not have had the opportunity to see the stack trace

Answer (score -1):

Try using `println` instead of `write` `toServerWriter.println("dummy");`.  The server may be waiting for the newline character.